# Replacing text in <a> tag which contains an <i>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an anchor tag which containes a nested icon and some text. When I try to update the text, the icon is removed. Here is the example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWyj/)

Which contains:

*HTML*:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="bin"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove Selected (0)</a>
```

*JS*:

```
$(function(){
    var selectCount = 0;
    $("#bin").click(function(){
        selectCount++;
        $(this).text(" Remove Selected ("+selectCount+")");
    });
});
```

I've tried to replace the selector with `$(this).children(":text")` but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your HTML, an easy solution would be put the number in its own `span` element:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="bin">
    <i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove Selected (<span class="counter">0</span>)
</a>
```

Then you can select that element and change its content:

```
$(this).children('.counter').text(selectCount);
```

---

However if you cannot change the HTML:

> I've tried to replace the selector with `$(this).children(":text")` but to no avail.

You cannot select text nodes with selectors. However, you can use [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all child nodes, not only elements nodes. Then you can [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) those nodes for the node you want to change:

```
$("#bin").click(function(){
   selectCount++;
   $(this).contents().filter(function() {
       return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Remove Selected") > -1;
   }).get(0).nodeValue = " Remove Selected ("+selectCount+")";
});
```

Since the `a` element might contain other text nodes as well (every line break and indentation in your HTML code will be be converted to a DOM text node), checking the content of the text node might be necessary.

Comment: I don't think `text()` works on text nodes. Your code on the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/FZWyj/16/ Let me know if I've made a mistake here.

Comment: Mmmh. I could swear it used to work. Have to investigate on that. Thanks!

Comment: Felix, I ended up doing a `$.each(.contents(),... if(this.nodeType===3){...})`

Answer (score 3):

To change the value of the first Text Node, you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    var selectCount = 0;
    $("#bin").click(function(){
        selectCount++;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var childNode = this.childNodes[i];
            if(childNode.nodeType === 3) {
                childNode.textContent = " Remove Selected ("+selectCount+")";
                return;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`nodeType === 3` means a Text Node - More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/FZWyj/13/

Comment: this is exactly the solution I was looking for. I realised that it was replacing the inner html (from my attempt) and was looking for a way to zone in of the text itself. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because you replace the whole content of the `a` tag. Try somehting like this:

```
$(function(){
    var selectCount = 0;
    $("#bin").click(function(){
        selectCount++;
        $(this).html('<i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove Selected ('+selectCount+')');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZWyj/18/

Answer (score 1):

Text method removing the entire `<i class=icon-trash></i>` also.Use html and apply the class of icon

```
$(function(){
    var selectCount = 0;
    $("#bin").click(function(){
      selectCount++;
      $(this).html("<i class=icon-trash></i> Remove Selected ("+selectCount+")");
    });
});
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWyj/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try just updating the number in your string like this:

```
$(function(){
  var selectCount = 0;
  $("#bin").click(function(){
    selectCount++;
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\d+/, selectCount));
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWyj/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using css3 you could use a `span` element with [data attribute:](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Css:

```
span[data-iterator]:before {
    content: attr(data-iterator);
}
```

Html:

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger" id="bin">
  <i class="icon-trash"></i> 
    Remove Selected (<span data-iterator="0"></span>)
 </a>
```

Click handler:

```
 $("#bin").click(function(){
   $(this).find('[data-iterator]').attr('data-iterator',++selectCount);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jQuery, but when I understood correctly, you want to update the text without deleting the old one?

In pure JavaScript I would do following:

```
link = document.getElementById("link");
link.innerHTML = link.innerHTML + " new text";
```

Comment: Please always review your answer and make sure you use proper grammar and formatting for your code.